# Clock arm perfect alignment problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

On a typical round $12$ hour clock with $3$ arms (hour, minute and second), at precisely what time will all $3$ arms be perfectly aligned on top of each other, with the exception of at $00$:$00$:$00$ hours?

High precision is of the essence in this problem. If we consider a time at $3$:$15$:$15$ the arms are not perfectly aligned because the minute clock would have moved forward from the "$15$" position by $\frac{15}{60}$ of a minute etc.

In this problem we assume that the arms move smoothly, rather than in 1 second increments. Any fraction of a second/minute/hour is possible.

I don't know if an answer exists to this problem, but a mathematical computation of a specific time or a proof that no answer exists is what I am looking for.

Comment: The LRC holds for three runners, so a solution is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that this happens at exactly $x$ hours after $00{:}00{:}00$.  At this time,

- the hour hand has travelled through an angle $x/12$ of a full circle;
- the minute hand has travelled through an angle $x$ of a full circle;
- the second hand has travelled through an angle $60x$ of a full circle.

If the hands are to lie on top of one another, these angles must all differ by an integer.  So we have
$$\frac{11x}{12}=m\ ,\quad 59x=n$$
where $m$ and $n$ are integers.  Eliminating $x$ gives
$$12\times59m=11n\ .$$
Therefore $m$ must be an integer multiple of $11$, so $x$ is an integer multiple of $12$.  Therefore the time is a multiple of $12$ hours after the $00{:}00{:}00$ position, and so the hands are still at the $00{:}00{:}00$ position.

That is, the three hands can never be **exactly** together, except at $00{:}00{:}00$.

Comment: "These angles must all differ by an integer" - in the problem, it is assumed that any fraction of second/minute/hour is possible, rather than to 1 second accuracy, which is what you assumed I believe. Does this change your answer?

Comment: No, that is not what I assumed, and it does not change my answer.  I am measuring angles in terms of full circles.  Two hands are on top of each other if the angles differ by an integer.  For example, if one hand has gone $1\frac1{11}$ times round the clock face and another has gone $13\frac1{11}$ times round, then they will be on top of each other.

Comment: I neither up or down voted... it was someone else. My reputation is too low to upvote :(

Comment: OK, thanks, no problem.

Comment: I think the table someone else provided with the angles is what you are trying to express here right?

Comment: I guess, though as they didn't show any working, it is hard to be confident that their table is correct.  IMO the algebraic working shows clearly that there is no solution except $00{:}00{:}00$.

Answer (score 1):

The following table enumerates each occasion in which the hour arm and the minute arm are aligned, along with the exact time it happens and the angle of each of the three arms (counted clockwise from 12, up to two-digit accuracy):
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
\text{Hr}&\text{Min}&\text{Sec}&\text{Angle of hr}&\text{Angle of min}&\text{Angle of sec}&\\
\hline
12&0&0&0^{\circ}&0^{\circ}&0^{\circ}\\
1&5&27\mathord.27&32\mathord.73^{\circ}&32\mathord.73^{\circ}&163\mathord.64^{\circ}\\
2&10&54\mathord.55&65\mathord.45^{\circ}&65\mathord.45^{\circ}&327\mathord.27^{\circ}\\
3&16&21\mathord.82&98\mathord.18^{\circ}&98\mathord.18^{\circ}&130\mathord.91^{\circ}\\
4&21&49\mathord.09&130\mathord.91^{\circ}&130\mathord.91^{\circ}&294.55^{\circ}\\
5&27&16\mathord.36&163\mathord.64^{\circ}&163\mathord.64^{\circ}&98\mathord.18^{\circ}\\
6&32&43\mathord.64&196\mathord.36^{\circ}&196\mathord.36^{\circ}&261\mathord.82^{\circ}\\
7&38&10\mathord.91&229\mathord.09^{\circ}&229\mathord.09^{\circ}&65\mathord.45^{\circ}\\
8&43&38\mathord.18&261\mathord.82^{\circ}&261\mathord.82^{\circ}&229\mathord.09^{\circ}\\
9&49&5\mathord.45&294\mathord.55^{\circ}&294\mathord.55^{\circ}&32\mathord.73^{\circ}\\
10&54&32\mathord.73&327\mathord.27^{\circ}&327\mathord.27^{\circ}&196\mathord.36^{\circ}
\end{array}
\end{align*}

As you can see, midnight and noon are the only times when *all three* arms are perfectly aligned.

---

How can this be computed? Note that during an hour, the hour arm proceeds $360/12=30$ degrees. During a minute, the minute arm proceeds $360/60=6$ degrees. Hence, when it is $h$ hours and $m$ minutes (where $m$ is allowed to be non-integer so as to incorporate all smaller units of time like second, milliseconds, etc.; but $h$ must be an integer), the hour and minute arms are aligned when
\begin{align*}
30\left(h+\frac{m}{60}\right)=6m.\tag{$\spadesuit$}
\end{align*} The left-hand side measures the number of hours, including the fractional $m/60$ hours, times 30, which is the number of degrees the hour arm proceeds in the course of one hour. The right-hand side measures the number of minutes times 6, which is the number of degrees the minute arm proceeds during a minute. If the two arms were to be aligned, then these two quantities must be equal. Rearranging gives: $$m=\frac{60h}{11}.\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ From this, you can compute seconds using $$s=60\left(m-\lfloor m\rfloor\right),$$
given that there are sixty seconds in a minute, where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function.

Once you have $h$ and $m$ [$h$ runs from $1$ to $10$, and $m$ is given by ($\clubsuit$) for any fixed $h$], you can compute the (common) angle of the hour arm and the minute arm as given by ($\spadesuit$). Also, the angle of the second arm is given by $6s$, given that it proceeds six degrees each second in order to complete the $360^{\circ}$ circle in sixty seconds.

One final remark. If $h=11$, then ($\clubsuit$) gives $m=60$. But this is actually the same as noon/midnight! This observation gives rise also to an interesting riddle:
\begin{align*}
\textit{In the course of a day, how many times are the hour arm and the minute arm perfectly aligned?}
\end{align*}
The answer is:

> 22, not 24.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers. I accept yours.

Comment: @CSLover: Do you really, though? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have played around with the equations of clock hands before, but without the seconds hand. What I *can* contribute is an equation for the angle of the hour and minute hand.

For the minute hand the angle from the twelve o'clock position is $6m$ where $m$ is the minute.

For the hour hand is half the minutes past twelve which is $${60h+m} \over {2}$$
where $h$ is hours. To find where they are equal, set the equations equal, however you need an expression for the angle of the seconds hand.

**Edit**

The result you get from setting them equal is
$$m=\frac{60}{11}h=h\cdot5.\overline{45}$$
so you can plug in hours ($h$) from 0 to 11.
So you don't need an expression for the seconds hand after all.
These answers will have repeating decimals in them, but you have stated that any fraction of a second can be used.